# Create limited list per row with key and value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So I need todo something like this, as I have got it to work, but I need todo it with key and values. So I have an array that has states and values. So I want to be able to create this result where I can echo out state and values.

This is not the whole array but example:

```html
$states = array('AL'=>"Alabama",
            'AK'=>"Alaska",
            'AZ'=>"Arizona",
            'AR'=>"Arkansas",
            'CA'=>"California",
            'CO'=>"Colorado",
            'CT'=>"Connecticut",
            'DE'=>"Delaware",
            'FL'=>"Florida",
            'GA'=>"Georgia",
```

```html
$states = statesList();
            $lists  = array_chunk($states, 10);
            $number = 1;
            foreach ($lists as $items) {
            echo '<ul class="row', $number++, '">';
            foreach ($items as $item) {
            echo '<li>', $item, '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

just a simple foreach will work.

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($states as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key." is ".$value. "<br>";
    $count++;
    if ($count == 5)  // print only 5 elements
        break;
}
```

output:

```
AL is Alabama
AK is Alaska
AZ is Arizona
AR is Arkansas
CA is California
```

Comment: I need to limit the list with only 10 in a row.

Comment: edited my answer. :) Please accept the answer and close this thread!

Comment: Okay maybe I am not explaining what I am needing correctly, so I want to print the full list in the array, I only want 10 items in each list. So the original code I have works todo that, excpet I need todo it with key and value.